# Display Image BLOB type in QML

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qml, blob

I got this problem 2 days ago, it's difficult to solve this problem. I spent much time to search/research but i don't receive any result.

Please help me.

Here my problem :

I have one table database, it has a column BLOB type, i query it, get data image and display it in listview qml. But it failed !!!

Here is my code

MDisplayImage.h

```
#ifndef MDISPLAYIMAGE_H
#define MDISPLAYIMAGE_H
#include <QQuickPaintedItem>
#include <QImage>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
class MDisplayImage:public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged)
public:
    explicit MDisplayImage(QQuickItem * parent): QQuickPaintedItem(parent){}
    QImage image() const { return *m_image;}
    void setImage(const QImage& image);
    void paint(QPainter *painter) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    MDisplayImage();
private:
    QImage* m_image;
signals:
   void imageChanged();
};

#endif // MDISPLAYIMAGE_H
```

MDisplayImage.cpp

```
#include "MDisplayImage.h"
#include <QPainter>

MDisplayImage::MDisplayImage()
{

}
void MDisplayImage::setImage(const QImage &image){
    m_image = image;
    emit imageChanged();
    update();
    setImplicitHeight(image.height());
    setImplicitWidth(image.width());
}
void MDisplayImage::paint(QPainter *painter){
    m_image = m_image.scaled(width(), height(),Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
    if(m_image.isNull()) return;
    painter->drawImage(0,0,m_image);

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "MDataBaseTableModel.h"
#include "MDisplayImage.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MDataBaseTableModel *objectModel = new MDataBaseTableModel(0);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    qmlRegisterType<MDisplayImage>("ImageConnected",1,0,"MDisplayImage");
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("modelSQL",objectModel);
    engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

and main.qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0
import ImageConnected 1.0
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 1350
    height: 760
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    header: ToolBar{
        Label{
            text: qsTr("Welcome")
            font.pixelSize: 50
            anchors.centerIn: parent
        }
    }

    SwipeView {
        id: swipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        currentIndex: tabBar.currentIndex

        Page1 {
            StackView{
                id: stackView
                anchors.fill: parent
                initialItem: MainPage{}
            }
        }



        Page {
            Label {
                text: qsTr("Second page")
                anchors.centerIn: parent
            }
        }
    }

    footer: TabBar {
        id: tabBar
        currentIndex: swipeView.currentIndex
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("First")
        }
        TabButton {
            text: qsTr("Second")
        }
    }

}

//}
```

MainPage.qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
Page {
    //property Image test
    GridView {
        id: gridViewPro
        x: 50
        y: 100
        width: 1350
        height: 760
        model : modelSQL
        delegate: ItemDelegate{
            width: 450
            height: 320

            SubProduct{}
            MouseArea{
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: stackView.push("qrc:/Detail.qml", {man : Vendor})
            }


        }
        highlight: Rectangle {
            width: 500
            height :400
            color: "red"; radius: 5
        }
        focus: true
        cellWidth: 500
        cellHeight: 400
    }

}
```

and the SubProduct.qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import ImageConnected 1.0
ColumnLayout{
    spacing: 0
    Rectangle{
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        Layout.preferredWidth: 450
        Layout.preferredHeight: 300
        RowLayout{
            spacing: 0
            Rectangle{
                Text{
                    text : Original //Original display fine in UI, it is column name of my database, this text show fine
                }
                id: imagePlace
                Layout.minimumWidth: 150
                Layout.minimumHeight: 300
                MDisplayImage{
                    id: newImage
                    width: 150
                    height:300
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    image: imageData //imagedata is a column of my database has type BLOB and it not display
                }

//                color: "#e0e1c5"
//                Text{
//                    text: number
//                }

            }
            Rectangle{
                id:infor
                Layout.minimumWidth: 300
                Layout.minimumHeight: 300
                ColumnLayout{
                    spacing: 0
                    Rectangle{
                        Layout.minimumWidth: 300
                        Layout.minimumHeight: 270
                        color: "#df745a"
                    }
                    Rectangle{
                        Layout.minimumWidth: 150
                        Layout.minimumHeight: 30
                        color: "yellow"
                        Button{
                            width: 300
                            height: 30
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
    Rectangle{
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
        Layout.preferredWidth: 450
        Layout.preferredHeight: 20
        color: "#8dd321"
//        Text{
//            text:name
//        }
    }
}
```

MDatabaseTableModel.h

```
#ifndef MDATABASETABLEMODEL_H
#define MDATABASETABLEMODEL_H
#include <QSqlTableModel>
#include <QSqlDatabase>

class MDataBaseTableModel:public QSqlTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MDataBaseTableModel();
    explicit MDataBaseTableModel(QObject * parent =0);
    void connectDb();
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
private:
    QSqlDatabase m_db;
};

#endif // MDATABASETABLEMODEL_H
```

MDatabaseTableModel.cpp

```
#include "MDataBaseTableModel.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QSqlError>
#include <QSqlTableModel>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QByteArray>
#include <QSqlQuery>
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QSqlError>
MDataBaseTableModel::MDataBaseTableModel()
{

}
MDataBaseTableModel::MDataBaseTableModel(QObject *parent):
    QSqlTableModel(parent)
{
    connectDb();
    QString nameTable = "productMarket";
    setTable(nameTable);
    QSqlQuery queryObject;
    queryObject.prepare("SELECT * FROM productMarket");
    queryObject.exec();
    this->setQuery(queryObject);
}
QVariant MDataBaseTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &idx, int role) const
{
    if (role < Qt::UserRole)
        return QSqlTableModel::data(idx, role);

    const QSqlRecord sqlRecord = record(idx.row());
    return sqlRecord.value(role - Qt::UserRole);
}
QHash<int, QByteArray> MDataBaseTableModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> colums;
    colums[Qt::UserRole] = "productID";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+1] = "Name";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+2] = "Type";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+3] = "Vendor";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+4] = "Original";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+5] = "Price";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+6] = "State";
    colums[Qt::UserRole+7] = "imageData";
    colums[Qt::UserRole +8] = "Promotion";
    return colums;
}
void MDataBaseTableModel::connectDb(){
    m_db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
    m_db.setDatabaseName("/home/actiso/Test_DB/example.db");

    if(m_db.open()){
        qDebug()<< "query to database successfully";
    }else{
        qDebug()<< "query to database failed"<< m_db.lastError();
    }
}
```

When run program, the text of database show well,but image can not display. `setImage()` function is not called, but still call `paint()` function

Please help me !!!

Comment: Are you able to display the image using QtWidgets correctly?

Comment: @m7913d : Yes , the image is got and display in QtWidgets correctly, I don't know the imageData variables has data or not in qml

Comment: Could you explain how you implemented the MDataBaseTableModel class?

Comment: Sorry, my code is quite long. I want to display image which is store in database in BLOB type via Gridview qml. But text or INTEGER show correctly, but image BLOB type is not displayed

Comment: @eyllanesc: I have edit MDatabaseTableModel class

Comment: Line 24 SubProduct.qml has error : "Unable to assign QByteArray to QImage"

Comment: I think the problem is how you have implemented your model, I have just joined it with my custom model and if it is showing the images.

Comment: see this: http://imgur.com/a/Z1Z1M

Comment: Can you tell me how to fix my model, I am newbie qml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the recommendations found in: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html

The problem is that the class that custom QQuickPaintedItem is waiting for a QImage type data, so you must return one of this type in your model:

**sqltablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef SQLTABLEMODEL_H
#define SQLTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>

class SqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
public:

    SqlTableModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase());
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
};

#endif // SQLTABLEMODEL_H
```

**sqltablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "sqltablemodel.h"
#include <QSqlRecord>
#include <QImage>

SqlTableModel::SqlTableModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db):
    QSqlTableModel(parent, db)
{
}

QVariant SqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    QVariant value;

    if (index.isValid()) {
        if (role < Qt::UserRole) {
            value = QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
        } else {
            int columnIdx = role - Qt::UserRole - 1;
            QModelIndex modelIndex = this->index(index.row(), columnIdx);
            value = QSqlTableModel::data(modelIndex, Qt::DisplayRole);
            //imagedata is the name of blob type column
            if(roleNames().value(role) == "imagedata")
                return QImage::fromData(value.toByteArray());
        }
    }
    return value;
}


QHash<int, QByteArray> SqlTableModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    for (int i = 0; i < record().count(); i ++) {
        roles.insert(Qt::UserRole + i + 1, record().fieldName(i).toUtf8());
    }
    return roles;
}
```

*Note:* The advantages of this implementation is that the roles are created automatically with the names of each field in the table

Output:

[image]

Comment: I get error in SubProduct.qml ,line 24 : "Unable to assign QByteArray to QImage". I think the model return QByteArray and will call setImage() function in MDisplayModel, but input this function is QImage. I still not display image. tell me where did you connect to database ?

Comment: Share all your code and all files with .db through drive, dropbox or similar, I will fix it for you.

Comment: Here is my project and .db file :https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1yjrUGDJ2sCZUh6U3pDVkh0dlE

Comment: Here is the working code, I have deleted elements that you did not use, or previous tests of your code since it bothered me, please do not forget to mark my answer as correct and also places the correct location of the database, this you lo You must do in main.cpp. https://gist.github.com/eyllanesc/e82ec52222793966991844cd61419f73

Comment: Thank you very much